# How to overwrite __init__ while saving the old __init__ inheriting from OrderedDict

Tags: python

```
class AppendiveDict(c.OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self,func,*args):
        c.OrderedDict.__init__(args)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value,):
        if key in self:
            self[key] = func(self[key])
        else:
            c.OrderedDict.__setitem__(self,key,value)
```

I have this class that is supposed to apply the func function to items already in the dictionary. If I do `c.OrderedDict.__init__(args)` it tells me descriptor `__init__` needs an ordereddict and not a tuple.

If I change `c.OrderedDict.__init__(self)` then an empty ordereddict shows up in the representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to pass both arguments, because `c.OrderedDict.__init__` needs to know on which instance it's supposed to operate and with which arguments:

```
import collections as c

class AppendiveDict(c.OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        c.OrderedDict.__init__(self, args)  # pass self AND args
```

Or to use `super` with `args` only (because `super` returns a bound method that already knows on which instance it is called):

```
class AppendiveDict(c.OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        super().__init__(args)
```